# User defined log files for SOAP requests and Responses in Websphere 8

Tags: web-services, logging, soap, websphere

I have a Soap based web services running in websphere 8. Since we have he trace.log, which have the Webservices request and response XML. I am trying to log it to a different file apart from trace.log.

To be very precise, If my service is HelloWorldService. I would like to log the SOAP requests in service_helloworld.log. I have defined the appenders and loggers in log 4j already. But I am looking into a way where I could configure websphere to redirect the webservices traces to that file.

I still could write a interceptor, but I am trying it in websphere configs. Please help

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you still have that problem... But I had the same one and I just fix it implementing a GenericHandler that interceps the request/response.

Take a look:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0511_phung-lu/0511_phung-lu.html